# Angular2/TypeScript: Why is document scroll event not firing for every pixel?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a very lightweight and simple lazy scroll directive. I want to use it like so:

`<some-element lazyScroll [lazyScrollDistance]="100" (lazyScrollAction)="loadMore()">...</some-element>`

The `lazyScrollDistance` is the amount of pixels the user has to slide down from the top of your element for you to initiate the `lazyScrollAction`. This will be triggered every subsequent 100 pixels, but never repeated when going backwards.

The code I have written achieves this, with one caveat: The scroll event is not fired eery 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc. pixels, but rather it is fired (depending on how fast I scroll) in chunks, like 1, 4, 10, 13, 15, etc..

This breaks my logic because I am expecting the scrolls to increment by one 100% of the time.

Can someone please advise me on this?

Here is the code:

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { WindowRefService } from 'core/services/window-ref/window-ref.service';

interface HitMap {
    [position: number]: boolean;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[lazyScroll]',
})
export class LazyScrollDirective {
    private hitMap: HitMap = {};

    @Input('lazyScrollDistance') scrollDistance = 100;
    @Output() lazyScrollAction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private windowRef: WindowRefService,
        private element: ElementRef,
    ) {
        const win = windowRef.nativeWindow;
        const el = element.nativeElement;

        document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            this.onScroll(win, el);
        });
    }

    onScroll(win: Window, el: any) {
        const currentPos = win.pageYOffset;

        if (this.hitMap[currentPos]) {
            return;
        }

        const elementTopRelativeToViewport = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const elementTopRelativeToDocument = elementTopRelativeToViewport + currentPos;
        const startBase = elementTopRelativeToDocument + this.scrollDistance;

        if (currentPos > startBase && currentPos % this.scrollDistance === 0) {
            this.hitMap[currentPos] = true;
            this.lazyScrollAction.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `WindowRefService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function getWindow(): any {
    return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRefService {
    get nativeWindow(): any {
        return getWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want it to fire when the window is scrolled to EXACTLY 100 pixels past the element? (And at 200, 300, etc...?)

Comment: Yes, precisely. And I have the `hitMap` to prevent it from firing when the user scrolls back up and hits the previously loaded spot again.

Comment: Don't think this will work because the browser itself doesn't always scroll one pixel at a time. If it did, the event would fire thousands of times at once if the page was long and the user hit the 'end' key, for example. I think the best you can do is keep track of the previous scroll position, and fire the event if previous scroll is < 100 and current scroll is >= 100.